# Free WPF obfuscator / protect from reverse engineering?

Tags: c#, wpf, obfuscation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Obfuscator which supports WPF properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994948/obfuscator-which-supports-wpf-properly)

I am looking for a free WPF obfuscator to protect the code inside my application, which includes my API key.

I have seen Dotfuscator but as I understand the free version does not include obfuscating WPF applications.

How should I go about protecting my application from reverse engineering?

Thanks

Comment: If you really want to protect against reverse engineering, don't use .NET

Comment: @thecoop - If you're going to go that route, you might was well say that they shouldn't write their app at all. If somebody wants to reverse engineer code, no matter how it is written, they'll find a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been asked around here several times before.
Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805549/free-obfuscation-tools-for-net

Anyhow, seems Eazfuscator : http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net  is a really good choice.

Update: Eazfuscator.NET will not obfuscate WPF XAML, to my knowledge, however I don't know a *free* tool that does. A paid version can though; see this http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/compare-editions

Answer (score 0):

A quick search of [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=wpf+obfuscator) makes it look like it is not possible to entirely obfuscate a WPF application.  You can obfuscate the code behind, but not the XAML.

http://windowsclient.net/blogs/rob_relyea/archive/2009/10/27/obfuscation-of-wpf-applications-status-update.aspx

Comment: I don't think it's correct, that you can't obfuscate XAML, see here: http://www.preemptive.com/blog/archives/179